# Integrating using Simpson's Rule

Tags: definite-integrals, simpsons-rule

Suppose there are functions

$$ g(x) = \frac{(2 \cdot \lfloor x\rfloor)}{(3\cdot x - \lfloor x \rfloor)} \tag{1}$$

and

$$ f(x) =\frac{\mid g(x)\mid}{ g(x)} \tag{2} $$

Now how do we do the definite integral of $f(x)$ with limits $-10$ to $0$ using Simpson's rule.

Simpson's Rule states that integral of $f(x)$ limited from $a$ to $b$ is approx equal to

$$ \frac{b-a}{6} \cdot \left[f(b) + 4 \cdot f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) + f(a) \right] \tag{3}$$

Putting $ f(0)$ returns an indeterminant value in the form of $0/0$ which cannot be used to carry out further Calculations. Hence what are we supposed to do in such a scenario?

Comment: hi .. what have you done so far ?

Comment: In the part in Simpson's rule where you have to calculate f(upper limit), I am getting problem as putting 0 in the function returns an indeterminant value

Comment: Do you think you can edit your question to show more precisely what you mean ?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Please format your equations with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).